# programmatically xcode build(ios library) -is it possible?

Tags: xcode, flutter, fastlane, xcode-command-line-tools

I have mac descktop app(flutter, small obfuscator for objective-c code). after obfuscation of the source code, the user builds a ios library in XCode. is it possible to start the build process from my application?

These my options are:

1. [Xcode Command Line Tools](https://mac.install.guide/commandlinetools/index.html) - it's very similar, but looks a bit complicated.
   Also, I don't know yet how to use the terminal (terminal commands) in the desktop application - is it even possible?
2. [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) -this tool is more for deployment. can i use this to build locally?

What do you recommend? maybe there are other options?

Answer (score 0):

read below documentaion and set flutter path so it can be runable in terminal or you can get help from youtube to set flutter path

then simply open terminal and run below comands one by one

1.open -a simulator
this command open ios emulator

2. write cd and drag your project folder path
   cd .../example
3. flutter run
   ✅your app launch in emulator

flutter path set details

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos